# Increase power for particular frequencies

Tags: fft, ifft

I am taking an FFT of two signals ( A very clean signal, with little noise, and a very noisy signal).

***Signal A***

The signal that has very little noise has the following FFT output:

[image]

***Signal B***

The FFT output that has more noise, has the following FFT output:

[image]

Is it possible to change the power levels of the frequency bins of ***Signal B*** to be more in line of that of ***Signal A***, so that once an iFFT is performed of ***Signal B***, a cleaner version comes out as a result?

Comment: First of all, considering every second bin is zero: that's a pretty special signal! And, considering that speciality: are you positively sure that "shaping" the spectrum actually does what you want to achieve? What is that? (I'm trying to make sure we're not subject to the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here)